# Discriminant Analysis Package for WEKA

Tags: classification, weka

I have downloaded "discriminantAnalysis 1.0.0" for WEKA.  How do you use/open it using WEKA?

I opened "Package Manager" in WEKA but there is no package for discriminantAnalysis 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The following was done using Weka 3.7.11:

The discriminatAnalysis package was visible and available about half-way down the list (It didn't appear to be in order due to uppercase and lowercase package names).  Click on Install to Install.

[image: Discriminant Analysis Package available from Package Manager]

Once you have restarted Weka, you should then be able to see the functions under the classifier section of the Weka Explorer.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Dear Matthew, Thank you so much. I did what you recommended. I can see "FLDA" under the function, but it is not activated. Why or How can I activate it?

Comment: It is likely the data.  I found that it worked for 10 numeric attributes and 1 nominal class, but not for nominal attributes.  I hope that helps in your ability to use the tool.  Good luck!